# Why is $\prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k - 1}(p_k-1) = n \prod_{p\mid n} \left(1 - \frac {1}{p} \right)$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, totient-function

Today in my group theory class, my teacher was proving the following statement:

> If $n \in \mathbb N$ and if $n = \prod_{k = 1}^t p_k ^{\alpha_k}$ is it's prime factorization, then:
> $$\varphi(n) = n\prod_{p\mid n } \left(1 - \frac {1}{p} \right)$$
> where $p$ is prime.

Here $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function. The proof he presented is the following:

---

Let $\mathbb Z^*_n$ denote the multiplicative group of integers mod $n$.

If $m,n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then:

$$\mathbb Z^*_n \times \mathbb Z^*_m \simeq \mathbb Z^*_{nm}$$

This means that $| \mathbb Z^*_{nm}| = | \mathbb Z^*_{n}|| \mathbb Z^*_{m}|$, thus:

if $m,n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then: $$\varphi(nm) =\varphi(n)\varphi(m)$$

So, if  $n = \prod_{k = 1}^t p_k ^{\alpha_k}$, then: $$\varphi(n)  = \prod_{k = 1}^t \varphi (p_k ^{\alpha_k})$$

We have that if $p$ is prime then:

$$\varphi(p^k) = p^{k - 1}(p-1)$$

So, putting all together we have that:

$$\varphi(n)  = \prod_{k = 1}^t \varphi (p_k ^{\alpha_k}) = \prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k - 1}(p_k-1)$$

And then the teacher claimed that $$\prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k - 1}(p_k-1) = n \prod_{p\mid n} \left(1 - \frac {1}{p} \right),$$

where $p$ is prime. This is the only step of the proof that my teacher just wrote on the board without a proper explanation and that's why I'm having some struggle understanding it. Why is this true?

Comment: Factor $p_k$ out of the parenthesis in the left-hand side.

Comment: It might be more transparent if you write the products out without $\prod$, as done on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Proof_of_Euler's_product_formula).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a product, so you can take out a factor of $n$ as a product of primes. Then, by definition, the $p_k$ are the $p|n$.

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k - 1}(p_k-1)& = \prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k}\left(1 - \frac {1}{p_k} \right)\\
& = \left(\prod_{k = 1}^t p_k^{\alpha_k}\right)\prod_{k = 1}^t\left(1 - \frac {1}{p_k} \right) \\
&= n \prod_{p|n} \left(1 - \frac {1}{p} \right)
\end{align}$$